# How to repeat a table on php based on MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have made a page on my website that has a table with information displayed whenever a new record is add on my MySQL database here is my code:

```
<?php
      while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryD))
            {   
     echo "<table width='800' border='0' align='center' style='margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: #FFFFFF;' border-radius: '5px;' cellspacing='0px' cellpadding='2px;'>";
       echo "<tbody>";
         echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Name" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='193' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Type" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='98' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Phone" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='98' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Age" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='148' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Gender" . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='160' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . "Natunality" . "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";

         echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Name"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Type"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Phone"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Age"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Gender"] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='93' class='generalFONT' style='border: 1px solid black;'>" . $r["Natu"] . "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
```

and here is my query:

```
$queryD = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");
```

All the code above is working fine but, my problem here is I want to repeat the table whenever a new user registered on the database. I have multiple record on my database but this code is showing only one table and only the first record. I want to show all the records, each one in a separated table. So how can I do that? hope you understand my question. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

try working with foreach

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

this is a example of php.net

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
```